# What is Alternative of IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>> in .net 6 for IntegrationTests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I saw IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory> in .net core 3 for IntegrationTests, now I want to write an integration test for a project which is .et6, what should I use instead of IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory> in .net 6 for IntegrationTests ?

Here is what I tried:

```
public class TicketControllerTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public TicketControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateDefaultClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/Tickets/Test");

        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Here I get this error:

[image]

Comment: `IClassFixture` is part of xUnit - it's always been available in all verisons of .NET and is documented here: https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I was trying to use unconfigured startup (default) in IClassFixture. I think my solution will solve your question indirectly.

I solved this problem by change my program.cs. first, I add this code as ProgramBuilder in my api:

```
public class ProgramBuilder
{
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder<T>(params string[] args)
    where T : Startup
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(defaults => defaults.UseStartup<T>());
    }
}
```

then in my program.cs I add this code:

```
var myHost = ProgramBuilder.CreateHostBuilder<Startup>(args).Build();
    myHost.Run();
```

I used this link it helped me alot:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40361

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IClassFixture` in all versions of `.Net`.

I think your error comes from `Program.cs`, put your codes here to help you.